# OMR based software for .Net application

Tags: c#, image

I am looking for a Optical Mark Recognition software to read the scanned documents and automatically process them.

These documents are created from a ASP.net Web application. Users will fill in those printed forms which have a barcode and then scan the same.

If you have any idea or used it appreciate if you could suggest something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Document_Imaging for scanning documents.

http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/ Tessnet 2 is an open source .Net based OMR assembly.

I have never done barcode scanning or reader implementation, but I found this on google. Hope this helps. http://www.onbarcode.com/products/net_barcode_reader/

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Softek's Barcode Reader Toolkit](http://www.bardecode.com/en/products/56-barcode-reader-toolkit-for-windows.html) for reading barcodes off of bitmaps before, and it worked very well. It's fairly configurable and speedy.